# Sphinx returns wrong document ids

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

My sphinx search returns wrong results, if I search for a keyword, the document ids returned do not contain that keyword.

Here is how I created conf settings:

```
source source_name
{
    type                = mysql

    sql_host            = ******
    sql_user            = ******
    sql_pass            = ******
    sql_db              = ******
    sql_port            =   # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query_pre           = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
        sql_query_pre                   = SET NAMES utf8
        sql_query                       = \
                SELECT \
                        P.ID AS ID, P.TITLE AS TITLE, P.TITLE AS TITLE_SORT \
                FROM \
                        PRODUCT P \
                WHERE \
                        P.ISVALID='Y'

    sql_attr_string         = TITLE_SORT

    sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID=$id
}

index index_name
{
    source              = source_name
    path                = /path/to/data/file_name
    docinfo             = extern
    min_word_len            = 1
    charset_type            = utf-8
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit           = 128M
}

searchd
{
    listen              = 3312 # port is deprecated from 2.1+
    log             = /path/to/log/searchd.log
    query_log           = /path/to/log/query.log
    read_timeout            = 5
    max_children            = 30
    pid_file            = /path/to/log/searchd.pid
    max_matches         = 1000
    seamless_rotate         = 0
    preopen_indexes         = 0
    unlink_old          = 1
    compat_sphinxql_magics      = 0
}
```

One important thing is that **If I search with the test.php tool, I can see that the attribute value shows products with searched keywords, but document ids are still wrong, which makes me thing why it is returning wrong document ids**

Another important thing is that on the same machine and same conf file, I created an index for another mysql database and it works fine.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is an example:

I search for "professional" and I get this result

```
1. doc_id=33285, weight=102, title_sort=Wella Professional BezoplachovÃÂ½ kondicionÃÂ©r pro objem vlasÃÂ¯ SP Volumize 150 ml, manufacturer_id=217, category_id=4648, min_price=0, product_rating=4294967295, filter_userid=(2714222508,3149373076)
2. doc_id=33286, weight=102, title_sort=Wella Professional ÃÂ ampon pro lesk vlasÃÂ¯ SP Shine Define 250 ml, manufacturer_id=217, category_id=3046113, min_price=0, product_rating=4294967295, filter_userid=(2714222508,3149373076)
3. doc_id=33287, weight=102, title_sort=Wella Professional ÃÂ ampon pro barvenÃÂ© vlasy SP Color Save 250 ml, manufacturer_id=217, category_id=3046113, min_price=0, product_rating=4294967295, filter_userid=(2714222508,3149373076)
```

.. and so on ..

You can see that the title_sort field has the word professional in it, but the doc_ids returned (33285, 33286, 33287) are not these records.

This below is the id - title data from database

```
33285   Avon Čisticí tonikum na tělo proti akné ve spreji Blemish Clearing 100 ml
33286   Biotherm Pleťový krém a sérum 2v1 pro navrácení pružnosti normální až smíšené pleti Age Fitness Elastic 30 ml AKCE
33287   Avon Dětský šampon Barbie® 200 ml
```

While the results you see in the title_sort above are tied to these ids:

```
32854   Wella Professional Bezoplachový kondicionér pro objem vlasů SP Volumize 150 ml
32855   Wella Professional Šampon pro lesk vlasů SP Shine Define 250 ml
32856   Wella Professional Šampon pro barvené vlasy SP Color Save 250 ml
```

Comment: It might help to define 'wrong'. How exactly are they wrong? Wrong order, wrong values. missing expected documents, got extra ones etc...

Comment: wrong means that the ids returned are for records that totally do not have those keywords

Comment: @barryhunter: I have updated my post to add an example to show what I get in sphinx/api/test.php search, hope this explains something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, issue is solved! It was a stupid mistake by our hosting support.

They created a new database and transferred old db data into it. The old database was corrupted.

I found this out when I created a duplicate table of the original and then tried to index it, sphinx gave me error that table does not exist, and that clicked my mind and I compared the database settings on site and sphinx.conf

I did not find an issue like mine on any forums and google, apart from one that had a similar configuration problem. **So if you are reading this answer to find a solution for a similar problem, then you must check your configuration and confirm that your conf file is pointing to the correct database and table.** This will save you days, may be weeks of pain :).